# "programming pearls": Strings of Pearls

Tags: c, casting, qsort, markov

In column 15.3, the author introduced how to generate text randomly from an input document.  The author also gave the [source code](http://www.cs.bell-labs.com/cm/cs/pearls/markov.c).

```
qsort(word, nword, sizeof(word[0]), sortcmp);
int sortcmp(char **p, char **q)
{   return wordncmp(*p, *q);
}
```

I've been confused by the above lines in the source code. 
The last argument of [qsort](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/qsort/) is:

```
int comparator ( const void * elem1, const void * elem2 ).
```

But the definition of sortcmp is different. Actually, the source code cannot compiled in my VS2010.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this code was originally compiled with a more forgiving (or less standard-compliant) compiler. The idea seems to be that the canonical `void *` arguments of the comparator function are interpreted as `char **` so that `wordncmp()`, which is an implementation of lexicographical comparison of up to length `n`, can be applied to them.

Declaring the function as expected (i.e. taking two `const void *` arguments) and making the type casts explicit appears to solve the problem (tested with GCC 4.7.0):

```
int sortcmp(const void *p, const void *q) {
  return wordncmp(*(const char **)p, *(const char **)q);
}
```

I also had to modify the declaration of the `wordncmp()` function:

```
int wordncmp(const char *p, const char* q)
{
  /*.. Definition unchanged.. */
}
```